# Powershell Script Using Runspaces

Tags: powershell, scripting, runspace

I am new to PowerShell, and just for practice I got instructions to, "Read in fortune 100 URLs to an array...then using runspaces, connect to each one and write the page you get with Invoke-WebRequest to file."  Then I was given this link: https://www.zyxware.com/articles/4344/list-of-fortune-500-companies-and-their-websites

I have been reading all about runspaces.  Right now I'm working on getting my links into an array that I can then pull the first 100 URLs out of. Any help/advice would be appreciated.

The issue that I have now is that when I call the link variable, it won't give me the links.  It seems like I should be able to just call the $link variable so that I can get all the links and put it into an array. The only way that I can get all the links to come up is  by using  "$page.Links.href".  Can someone please explain to me why calling that variable won't work?

```
$page = Invoke-WebRequest https://www.zyxware.com/articles/4344/list-of-fortune-500-companies-and-their-websites

foreach($1 in $page.Links){
    if($1.href -like '*www*com'){
        Write-Host $1.href

        $link = $1.Links.href

    }
}

           $RunspacePool = [RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1, $Throttle)
$RunspacePool.Open()
```

Comment: why start with a task with runspaces (overly complicated) if you dont even know how to do a http query? you need to do 3 steps back and start with basics, else this looks like you randomly got a job you are not fit for (or trying to get)

Comment: No, It's just a friend of mine trying to teach me PowerShell, and he wants me to learn about runspaces

Comment: well that is a stupid starting point, you should start with basics, not with runspaces. I wont be able to do it properly from my memory having 5+ years of powershell experience.

Comment: lol, ill tell him you said that

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Go at this one step at a time.

Before ever doing something as advanced as runspaces, you should take a few quick PowerShell online courses and materials so you have a baseline. Especially since you say you've never really used PoSH.

> https://mva.microsoft.com/en-us/training-courses/getting-started-with-microsoft-powershell-8276
>
> https://youtube.com/results?search_query=beginner+powershell

There are several no-cost eBooks online ...

> https://powershell.org/ebooks

...as well as a ton of downloadable scripts for many things.

> https://powershellgallery.com

and long list's of resources...

> Windows PowerShell Survival Guide
>   https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/183.windows-powershell-survival-guide.aspx

First understand how to use the PoSH WebCmdlets.

```
Get-Command -Name Invoke-WebRequest| Format-Table -AutoSize

CommandType Name              Version Source                      
----------- ----              ------- ------                      
Cmdlet      Invoke-WebRequest 3.1.0.0 Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility


# Get paramter, example, full and Online help for a cmdlet or function

(Get-Command -Name Invoke-WebRequest|).Parameters
Get-help -Name Invoke-WebRequest| -Examples
Get-help -Name Invoke-WebRequest| -Full
Get-help -Name Invoke-WebRequest| -Online


Get-Command -Name Invoke-RestMethod | Format-Table -AutoSize

CommandType Name              Version Source                      
----------- ----              ------- ------                      
Cmdlet      Invoke-RestMethod 3.1.0.0 Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility


# Get paramter, example, full and Online help for a cmdlet or function

(Get-Command -Name Invoke-RestMethod ).Parameters
Get-help -Name Invoke-RestMethod  -Examples
Get-help -Name Invoke-RestMethod  -Full
Get-help -Name Invoke-RestMethod  -Online


Then search using the string 'Invoke-WebRequest to parse website for URLs'

Do that website URL parsing first, get that where you need it then move on to runspaces.
If you can't make the first part happen the runspaces is moot.
```

So, try to get the URL's with code you put together, then if you have issue with that, post what you've tried and the forum will try an pitch in. The same thing will apply to your second step of the runspace part.